# City State Bonuses - where can I see if they are applied?

Tags: civilization-6

I am playing my first game in Civ 6 (Vanilla). I am not quite clear how City State bonuses work.
For example, Brussels - while my civ is a suzerain of that city with 6+ envoys assigned, I am supposed to get:

- +2 Production in the capital when producing wonders, buildings, and districts;
- +2 Production in every Industrial Zone when producing wonders, buildings, and districts;
- Additional +2 Production in every Industrial Zone when producing
  wonders, buildings, and districts;
- Your cities get 15% Production towards Wonders.

When e.g. a wonder is built in my civ's capital (having an Industrial Zone), where can I see (witness) these +15% and +6 Production yields are applied?

City Status Yields Report does not seem to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

City state bonuses come in two flavors. Permanent bonuses that improve districts or buildings and suzerain bonuses. These are independent.

Permanent bonuses are awarded for 1, 3 respectively 6 envoys to the city state. The type of bonus depends on the city state. There are 6 different types. Search your in-game Civilopedia (Use the question mark in the top right-hand corner to open the Civilopedia.) for "City-State Types" for an overview. These bonuses, once gained, are awarded until the city state is defeated, you loose envoys (the AI rarely uses the related spy missions) or you are at war with the city state.

Suzerain bonuses are awarded once you are suzerain. You don't need 6+ envoys. 3 suffice if no other civilization holds equal or more influence (envoys) over the city state. The bonus is active as long as you are suzerain. Check the Civilopedia for "Suzerain" for an explanation.

You can check your envoys and city-state bonuses using the city-state pane as shown in the screenshot below.[image: View of the city-state panel]

Using this panel, you can check the bonuses at each envoy level and for suzerainty by hovering over the respective text. See the images below.
[image: View of the suzerainty bonus hover-over.]
[image: View of the envoy bonus hover-over.]

As you can see in the last screenshot, I have 3+ envoys in each of the two commercial city-states which gives me +2 gold each to my lighthouse as you can see on the left. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the answer I was looking for. I know what is in the city states report but the point is that I don't see the bonuses applied in the City's (current) production report.

Comment: In my last screenshot, you can see that the gold bonus added just fine to the Lighthouse. These bonuses are directly mentioned on the affected buildings or districts. Bonuses on, for example, production when producing units, will show up in the tooltip if you hover-over a city's production if it is building units.

Comment: _"These bonuses, once gained, are awarded until the city state is defeated or you loose envoys (the AI rarely uses the related spy missions)."_ IIRC the third exception to this is if you are actively at war against this city state (i.e. their suzerain is at war with you).

Comment: @Flater correct. However, since you only get the bonuses if you are the suzerain, they cannot go to war with you unless you actively choose yourself to go to war with them.

Comment: @Eric: The quote I referenced is about the permanent bonuses, not the suzerain bonuses.

Comment: @Flater you are correct, I tested this and can confirm that you do not get the permanent bonuses if you are at war with a city state.